# Firebase does not close Microsoft sign page when finished in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, authentication

When using Microsoft as a provider in Firebase Auth, after signing in `UIApplication:open:url` is called with the redirection. But there is nothing in the documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/microsoft-oauth) about how to handle it and to get the sign in page to close.

For GoogleAuthProvider you would call `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url...)` in `UIApplication:open:url` to handle the redirection, which closes the WebView and works great.

Can not find anything out there on how to handle the redirect.

```
var provider: OAuthProvider?

@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
 provider = OAuthProvider(providerID: "microsoft.com")


provider?.customParameters = [
    "prompt": "consent",
            "login_hint": "",
]



provider?.getCredentialWith(nil ) { credential, error in
        if error != nil {
            // Handle error.
        }

        print(credential?.provider)
        if let credential = credential {
            Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credential)
            { (authResult, error) in
                print(authResult?.additionalUserInfo?.profile)
                print(authResult?.user.providerID)
            }
        } else {

        }

    }

}
```

I would expect after the user has signed in, the Microsoft SignIn page would close and getCredentialWith completion would be called.

Comment: Have you added custom URL schemes? It should handle the redirect to your application provided `UIApplication:open:url` returns true for its case.

Comment: @Roohul If you mean com.googleusercontent.apps.xxxxxx custom URL scheme yes. After calling getCredentialWith and signing in to Microsoft the redirection does happen,  UIApplication:open:url is called with com.googleusercontent.apps.xxxxxx://firebaseauth/link?deep_link_id=xxxx. My question is what should I call in UIApplication:open:url to handle the redirection.

Comment: The issue was I had **FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled=NO** in Info.plist to try and resolve "Missing Push Notification Entitlement". This turns off swizzling and Firebase was not swizzling **UIApplication:open:url** and thus not handling the redirect from Microsoft after calling **getCredentialWith**. You can call **Auth.auth().canHandle(url)** in **UIApplication:open:url** if you need to set **FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled=NO**.